# nullPointerException on sharedpreferences helper class When running a test

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin, android-testing

I'm starting to use Kotlin on a little demo android app. I've created a `sharedpreferences` helper class which i'm trying to test with Junit and Mockito. Below is my sharedprefshelper:

```
public class SharedPrefsHelperImp( cont : Context) : SharedPrefsHelper {

val prefsname: String = "prefs"
var prefs: SharedPreferences? = null
var edit: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null


init {
    prefs = cont.getSharedPreferences(prefsname, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    edit = prefs!!.edit()
}



override fun getPrefsStringValue(key: String) : String {
    return prefs!!.getString(key, "")
}

 override fun addPrefsStringVal( key : String,  value: String)  {
        edit!!.putString(key, value).commit()
}

override fun getSharedPrefsBool(key : String): Boolean {
    return prefs!!.getBoolean(key, false)
}

override fun addSharedPrefsBool(key : String, value : Boolean) {
        edit!!.putBoolean(key, value).commit()
}
}
```

here is my test class:

```
class SharedPrefsHelperImpTest {

@Mock var  cont : Context? = null
@Mock var mockprefs : SharedPreferences? = null
@Mock var mockprefsedit : SharedPreferences.Editor? = null
var prefshelper : SharedPrefsHelper? = null

@Before
fun setUp() {

    //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    cont = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
    mockprefs = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences::class.java)
    mockprefsedit = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor::class.java)

    `when`(cont!!.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockprefs!!)
    `when`(mockprefs!!.edit()).thenReturn(mockprefsedit!!)

    prefshelper = SharedPrefsHelperImp(cont!!)
}

@Test
fun testNotNull(){
    Assert.assertNotNull(cont)
    Assert.assertNotNull(mockprefs)
    Assert.assertNotNull(mockprefsedit)
}

@Test
fun testItemAdded()
{
    prefshelper!!.addPrefsStringVal("thing", "thing")
    verify(mockprefsedit)!!.putString(anyString(), anyString())
}

@Test
fun testGetString()
{
    prefshelper!!.getPrefsStringValue("key")
    verify(mockprefs)!!.getString("key", "")
}

}
```

Issue is when I call `addPrefsValueString()` in the helper. the line

edit!!.putString(key, value).commit()

throws a null pointer exception? not sure why? I've setup the mock `sharedprefs` and  `sharedpreferences.Edit` in the test class method annotated with `@Before` (shown below)

```
@Before
fun setUp() {

    //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    cont = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
    mockprefs = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences::class.java)
    mockprefsedit = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor::class.java)

    `when`(cont!!.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockprefs!!)
    `when`(mockprefs!!.edit()).thenReturn(mockprefsedit!!)

    prefshelper = SharedPrefsHelperImp(cont!!)
   }
```

i'm sure my code is less than optimal.

EDIT:

Here's my fix for the `testItemAdded()` method. need to return the mock preferences editor on the first call.

```
@Test
fun testItemAdded()
{
    `when`(mockprefsedit?.putString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockprefsedit)
    `when`(mockprefsedit?.commit()).thenReturn(true)
    prefshelper!!.addPrefsStringVal("thing", "thing")

    verify(mockprefsedit)!!.putString(anyString(), anyString())
    verify(mockprefsedit)!!.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set expectations for the call below, on your mock object (`mockprefsedit`). As well for the object returned, on which `commit` is invoked.

```
edit!!.putString(key, value)
```

thanks
Sriram

Comment: ah yes. I see what I did now. sheer idiocy on my part!